# Embedding continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

$X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces. Assume a function $f\colon X\to Y$ be function such that

1. $f,f^{-1}$ continuous functions,
2. $f$ is one-to-one.

We say, see topology by Willard, $f$ is embedding  function, that is, there exists a homeomorphism between $X$ and subspace of $Y.$ I am okay with that. But I found somewhere they used continuous embedding function. The embedding is already continuous. what does it mean? Could you explain that for me? Thank you

Comment: What do you know about convergence of series?

Comment: I know the convergence of the series